# No consigo parar un hilo en ejercución

Tags: java, hilos

tengo desarrollado un programa (clon de Spotify) de manera que al hacer click en una canción, se seleccione, y al hacer click en reproducir, llame a un método de una clase que hace reproducir una canción. Si haces click por segunda vez, sobre el botón reproducir, llame a un método que pausa la canción. Sin embargo no funciona bien, pues la canción no consigue pararse, ¿alguien sabe como?

Éste es el código correspondiente al hilo.

```
    public class MusicaReproducir extends Thread{
    /**
     * Canción a reproducir
     */
    private Cancion cancion;
    private AudioInputStream audio;
/**
 * Constructor que recibe un objeto de tipo canción
 * @param nombre nombre del objeto de tipo Cancion
 */
    public MusicaReproducir(Cancion nombre) {
        super();
        this.cancion=nombre;
    }
    /**
     * Método que hace ejecutar el hilo
     */
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.run();
        String ruta="./musica";
        
        System.out.println("Estado del hilo INICIO "+Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());

        
        if (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            System.out.println("El hilo -->"+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" NO ESTÁ interrumpido");
            try {
                Player player;
                FileInputStream cancionAReproducir = new FileInputStream(ruta+"/"+cancion.getNombre());
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(cancionAReproducir);
                player=new Player(bis);
                player.play();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JavaLayerException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }else {
            System.out.println("El hilo -->"+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" ESTÁ interrumpido");
        }

        System.out.println("Estado del hilo FINAL "+Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());

    }
    
}
```

Éste es el código correspondiente a la clase que hace reproducir una canción.

public class ReproducirCanciones implements Reproductor{

```
private static MusicaReproducir reproducirCancion;

public static Cancion añadirCancion(Cancion cancion) {
    String nombreString=cancion.getNombre();
    return cancion;
}

/**
 * método que hace reproducir una cancion
 * @param botonReproducir 
 * @param Objeto cancion a reproducir
 * @param Evento que se ha usado
 */
public static void reproducir(Cancion cancion, ActionEvent e, JButton botonReproducir) {
    
    System.out.println("Cancion ---> "+cancion);
        /*
        reproducirCancion = new MusicaReproducir(cancion);
        reproducirCancion.start();*/
        reproducirCancion = new MusicaReproducir(cancion);
        reproducirCancion.start();
        System.out.println("Nombre del hilo reproducir funcion-->"+reproducirCancion.getName()+" estado "+reproducirCancion.isInterrupted());
        
    
    
}
public Cancion cancionAreproducir(Cancion cancion) {
    return cancion;     
}

public static void pausar(Cancion cancion, ActionEvent e, JButton botonReproducir) {
    
    reproducirCancion.interrupt();
    System.out.println("Nombre del hilo pausar funcion-->"+reproducirCancion.getName()+" estado "+reproducirCancion.isInterrupted());
    if(!reproducirCancion.isInterrupted()) {
        System.out.println("INTERRUMPIDO");
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        String ruta="./musica";
        try {
            Player player;
            FileInputStream cancionAReproducir = new FileInputStream(ruta+"/"+cancion.getNombre());
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(cancionAReproducir);
            player=new Player(bis);
            player.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JavaLayerException ex) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }       
}
```

Éste último, es la clase que selecciona una canción, y la manda a reproducir a la clase ReproducirCanciones.

/***************  HACER REPRODUCIR UNA CANCIÓNN *******************
* Evento al hacer click en una cancion.
*/

```
    listaCancionesPlaylist.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            Cancion cancion = (Cancion) listaCancionesPlaylist.getSelectedValue();//esto es un objeto de cancion
            cancionActual=cancion;              
        }
    });
    
    //CLICK EN REPRODUCIR
    //si lo hago con mouseClick, no funciona
    botonReproducir.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        byte click=0;
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            click=(byte) ((click +1)%2);
            System.out.println("Cancion seleccionada ---> "+cancionActual.getNombre());
            
            if(click==1) {
                System.out.println("Cantidad de clicks --> "+click);
                reproducirCanciones.reproducir(cancionActual, e, botonReproducir);;
            }else {
                System.out.println("Cantidad de clicks --> "+click);
                reproducirCanciones.pausar(cancionActual, e, botonReproducir)
            }
        }
    });
```

Enlace al proyecto en GitHub.---> https://github.com/juancastillam98/Proyecto-Spotifeo.git

Comment: el primer fraagmento de codigo no compila porque no tiene definicion de clase, te recomiendo verificar que tengas un [mcve]

Comment: te añado, lo que le falta al código.

Comment: Intenta extender a Runnable en vez de a Thread, esto te permitira un mejor control e incluso usar Observable

Comment: Vale, gracias por el consejo. Entonces es mejor extender Runnable que de Thread ?

Answer (score 0):

Intenta sacando la variable clik del metodo, haciendola global ya que cada vez que se llama al evento esta variable se inicializa siempre con  el valor de 0

```
  //variable global fuera del metodo (Declarada en la clase)
     public static byte click=0;     

    botonReproducir.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        click=(byte) ((click +1)%2);
        System.out.println("Cancion seleccionada ---> "+cancionActual.getNombre());
        
        if(click==1) {
            System.out.println("Cantidad de clicks --> "+click);
            reproducirCanciones.reproducir(cancionActual, e, botonReproducir);;
        }else {
            System.out.println("Cantidad de clicks --> "+click);
            reproducirCanciones.pausar(cancionActual, e, botonReproducir)
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: La variable click, la tengo para ver si he pulsado la primera o 2ª vez el botón. Cuando ejecuto el programa, y pulso por 2ª vez, le tengo puesto un sysout para ver que ocurre y evidentement funciona bien, me dice que el hilo está interrumpido, pero la canción sigue sonando.